# How do I calculate age mean & standard deviation using aggregate age?

Tags: excel, statistics, spss

My data set has an age range variable, but I would like to calculate the mean and standard deviation of age.

[image: distribution of age range]

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is categorical, there isn't a way to calculate the "true" sample mean and standard deviation of respondent age.  There are a few different ways you could estimate, depending on how sophisticated you'd like to get.

The simplest way would be to assign an age to each band (say, the mid-point) and summarize on that.  The downside is that you will be underestimating the standard deviation (clumping data together tends to do that).  To the extent your categories are not uniformly distributed (and from your image they don't appear to be), your estimate of the mean will also be off.

```
* set point estimates for each age band .
RECODE age (1=22) (2=30) (3=40) (4=50) (5=60) (6=70) (7=80) .
EXE .

* calculate mean and std dev .
MEANS age /CELLS MEAN STDDEV .
```

More sophisticated estimation techniques might try to account for skews in data (e.g. your sample seems to skew younger) and convert each age band into its own distribution.

For example, instead of assuming 203 respondents are age 22 (as is done in the code above), you might assume 25 respondents each are 18, 19, 20, ... 25.  More realistically than that even, you might assume that even *that* distribution skews younger (e.g. 50 18-yr olds, 40 19-yr old, etc etc).

Automated approaches to that would be interesting as its own question.  :)